# MariaDB query problems (ORDER BY ignored)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MySQL query that ran fine but my hosting proivder change my database to MariaDB.  The query in itself works fine but I can't get the sorting to work correctly as it did in MySQL.

Is there some syntax that has changed or is it not available anymore?

```
    SELECT
 id,
  name,
  position,
  player1,
  player1_thru,
  player1_to_par,
  player2,
  player2_thru,
  player2_to_par,
  player3,
  player3_thru,
  player3_to_par,
  team_total,
  IF (counter = 1, @rank:= placeholder, @rank) AS ranker
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    @c := @c +1 AS placeholder,
    IF(@a <> team_total, @b := @b := 1, @b :=0) AS counter,
    @a := team_total
  from(
    SELECT
        usopen_2018.id,
        usopen_2018.position
        , usopen_2018.name
       , usopen_2018.player1
       , player1_score.hole as player1_thru
       , player1_score.to_par_s AS player1_to_par
       , usopen_2018.player2
       , player2_score.hole as player2_thru
       , player2_score.to_par_s AS player2_to_par
       , usopen_2018.player3
       , player3_score.hole as player3_thru
       , player3_score.to_par_s AS player3_to_par
       , (player1_score.`to_par` + player2_score.`to_par` + player3_score.`to_par`) AS team_total
    FROM usopen_2018
    INNER JOIN leaderboard_A AS player1_score
      ON player1_score.name = usopen_2018.player1
      AND player1_score.tournament_name = 'U.S. Open'
      AND player1_score.year = 2018
    INNER JOIN leaderboard_A AS player2_score
      ON player2_score.name = usopen_2018.player2
      AND player2_score.tournament_name = 'U.S. Open'
      AND player2_score.year = 2018
    INNER JOIN leaderboard_A AS player3_score
      ON player3_score.name = usopen_2018.player3
      AND player3_score.tournament_name = 'U.S. Open'
      AND player3_score.year = 2018
    WHERE usopen_2018.cut = 0 AND usopen_2018.wd = 0
    ORDER BY team_total, player1, player2, player3, name
  )AS t
)AS FINAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` needs to be moved out one level.

Here's why.  MariaDB is *now* honoring the standard, which says that a subselect is an *unordered* set of rows.  That is, the inner `ORDER BY` can be ignored.  MariaDB has done so for the last few versions; MySQL is also doing so in the latest version.

In the past, MySQL and MariaDB blindly did any `ORDER BY` requested by the user.  And then fed the results, still in order, to the next stage of the query.

**LIMIT trick**

If that does not work, add `LIMIT 99999999` after the `ORDER BY` in the innermost `SELECT`.  This should keep the Optimizer from ignoring the `ORDER BY`, while not actually doing any 'limit'.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to rearrange my query and see if I can get it working.  I did try it and didn't get the required resultset.

Comment: @Alan - I added another approach.